# Vim visual selection delete/insert in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I was trying to find a replacement of vim's visual mode which is extremely useful, say I would like to delete the first two characters on the below two lines

```
11 line1
22 line2
```

in vim, I enter into the visual mode and select the region I want to delete, and delete it. Moreover I also can add to the column after

```
11
22
```

like

```
11 added line1
22 added line2
```

wiht Shift+I after selecting the column in visual mode. Is there a way to do the same in emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[cua-mode](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) provides exactly this sort of feature. You can turn it on with the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq cua-enable-cua-keys nil)
(cua-mode)
```

The first line is necessary to prevent `cua-mode` from replacing a bunch of standard keyboard shortcuts with Windows-style things (C-c for copy, C-x for cut etc).

Once you're in `cua-mode`, `C-enter` will turn on visual rectangles, which you can then expand with the movement keys (arrows, `C-n`, `C-f` etc) to cover the text you want to manipulate. While this is going on, hitting `enter` moves the cursor around the edges of the rectangle, and anything you type is inserted outside the rectangle on the same side as the cursor. The insertion matches the size of the rectangle, so if you want to add the same text to the beginning (or middle or end) of a bunch of lines at once, this is the fastest way to do it.

If you disabled the cua keybindings, then `C-w` will kill the contents of the rectangle.

It's kind of unfortunate that the rectangle bits of cua-mode aren't in their own mode, as lots of people who don't want the cua-mode bindings don't realize that the mode also has this very cool feature!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like Emacs' rectangle features.  You kind have to visualize a rectangle in your head between the point and the mark.

`C-x r k` to kill rectangle
`C-x r t` to fill rectangle with text.  You want a rectangle zero column wide to do your second request.

Comment: Or with `cua-selection-mode`'s rectangle editing features, you don't need to visualize the rectangle, because it does it for you. Use `M-x find-library RET cua-base RET` and Look for "CUA rectangle support" in the commentary.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely.  CUA-rectangle offers a more intuitive UI over this feature.  If you're new to Emacs, that's definitely THE starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the [emacs rectangle feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Rectangles.html) would be a solution

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like Vimpulse may be what you need:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vimpulse.el

> Vimpulse emulates Vim's most popular features, like Visual mode
>    and text objects. Vimpulse is a set of modifications to Viper, the
>    standard library that emulates vi. Vimpulse is not a minor mode;
>    as soon as it is loaded, Viper will start working in a more
>    Vim-like way.